# With python align text to camera

Tags: python

I want to add a text to an object, soft of like a label.
The thing is, when I do it with python, view_align=True doesn't work. The text keeps it's original orientation.

I'm not writing a plugin or anything, I have the script in a text file in blender and just run it.

I'm thinking that the view isn't active when I run the script and because of that the text doesn't know what view to orient towards.

Maybe I could find the rotation of the camera and use that to set the rotation of the text object.

Comment: consider using a track to constraint on the text to the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the idea while writing my question. I'm not very good at 3D math with matrices etc but it worked.

Maybe someone will be helped by this.

```
cam_rot = scene.camera.rotation_euler
bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(x,y,z))
textobject=bpy.context.object
textobject.rotation_euler = cam_rot
```